# Remove data from nested objects without mutating

Tags: javascript, immutability, redux, mutation

Is there any elegant way of removing an object from an array which is part of an array?
I have been working with React and Redux for a while now but get stuck several hours everytime I have to remove or insert data without mutating the state.

The reducer is an array containing objects which have an ID and another array with objects, like this:

```
[
 { id:123,
   items:[
           { id: abc,
             name: albert
           }, 
           ... 
         ]
 }, 
 ... 
]
```

I receive both IDs and need to remove the item with ID `abc`.

Comment: You should read this one and reconsider your state structure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135779/updating-nested-data-in-redux-store/32921731#32921731

Comment: Instead of passing the full complex array to the reducer, create a new reducer that receive's the item of the array as the state to make the change

Comment: Well, thats also a way of doing it. But than every time i need the items of the object with id:123, i have to "search" for dem. 
And another question, when i receive the JSON like this from the backend, how do i split it to several reducers? The fetching is done via an action which than goes to one reducer.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To remove an item from an array by id:

```
return state.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)
```

To remove a key from an object by id:

```
let copy = Object.assign({}, state) // assuming you use Object.assign() polyfill!
delete copy[action.id] // shallowly mutating a shallow copy is fine
return copy
```

(Bonus) The same with [object spread operator proposal](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html):

```
let { [action.id]: deletedItem, ...rest } = state
return rest
```

Comment: A combination of those is what i ended up using.

Comment: What does `deletedItem` do/mean/contain in the last example?

Comment: @Mbrevda `deletedItem` is just a variable name that's assigned the item that was deleted (the item assigned to `action.id`). You're turning your state into two new objects, one that has the rejected item, the other with the remaining items.

Comment: @MattMcDonald ah, makes sense! Which there was a syntax for ignoring/deleting while destructuring. Something like: `{!foo, !bar, ...rest}`

Comment: If you're using rest-spread, it currently does not work with numeric keys. In that case you have to use `[action.id.toString()]`. See the issue https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4196, and the proposed fix https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/3675

Comment: so elegant, I love {deletedItem,...rest} idea

Answer (score 2):

```
const remove = (state, bucketId, personId) => state.map(
  bucket => bucket.id === bucketId
    ? { ...bucket, items: bucket.items.filter(person => person.id !== personId) }
    : bucket,
);
```

Usage:

```
const state = [
  {
    id: 123,
    items: [
      {
        id: 'abc',
        name: 'Kinna',
      },
      {
        id: 'def',
        name: 'Meggy',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 456,
    items: [
      {
        id: 'ghi',
        name: 'Ade',
      },
      {
        id: 'jkl',
        name: 'Tades',
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(remove(state, 123, 'abc'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Underscore's reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject). It does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: It returns array not object.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide for plain Javascript, the most elegant way I can think of is to use `Array.prototype.reduce` to reduce the state:

```
var state = [
 { id: 123,
   items:[
           { id: 'abc',
             name: 'albert'
           }, 
           ... 
         ]
 }, 
 ... 
]

function filterOut (state) {
  return (bucketId, personId) => {
    return state.reduce((state, bucket) => {
      return state.concat(
        (bucketId === bucket.id) ?
          Object.assign({}, bucket, {items: bucket.items.filter((person) => person.id !== personId)}) :
          bucket
      );
    }, []);
  }
}

var newState = filterOut(state)(123, 'abc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [lodash's omit method](https://lodash.com/docs/#omit).

Be aware that importing lodash will increase your build size quite a bit. Keep it in check somewhat by importing just the specific method:
`import omit from 'lodash/omit';`

If possible, I suggest using the object spread operator as described in [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676025/3708864).

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue in this way

```
if(action.type === "REMOVE_FROM_PLAYLIST"){
        let copy = Object.assign({}, state) 
        delete copy.playlist[action.index].songs[action.indexSongs];

        return copy;
    }
```

hope it helps any one else.