# Object.assign - Update Specific Property

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, redux

Using React & Redux here:

My `State` looks something similar to this:

```
State : {
   First : {
      prop1 : "a",
      prop2 : "b"
   },
   ...
   Last : {
      prop1 : "c",
      prop2 : "d"
   }
}
```

My `Reducer` function looks like this:

```
const tabsState = ( state = initialTabState, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
    case( ENABLE_TAB ):
        return (
            Object.assign( {}, state, action.payload )
        );
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

For the `action.payload`, I only want to send data containing new values for `prop1`. My understanding of `Object.assign` is that the `sources` parameters only update the props, they do not over-write the objects in state, is that correct?

In the above, My action.payload is similar to this:

```
   First : {
      prop1 : "z"
   },
   Second : {
      prop2 : "x"
   },
   ...
```

It seems to be overwriting the `First` & subsequent objects within the State object. That is to say, that the new State returned by the `Reducer` does not have the 2nd prop of each object. `prop2`s

Comment: If you have issues with deep update state, consider changing your data structure to something else. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32921731/1297743) for example. Also, you can split your reducer and create special reducer for `First`, `Second` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you could use Immutable.js. I have found it incredibly helpful for dealing with redux and not mutating the state tree. For you specific case the operator you would need to `Map.mergeDeep()` Where Map is your immutable data structure. `MergeDeep` will act just like you are thinking Object.assign will. 
So for you case

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
const initialTabState = fromJS({
     {
       First : {
         prop1 : "a",
         prop2 : "b"
       },
     ...
       Last : {
         prop1 : "c",
         prop2 : "d"
       }
     }
})
const tabsState = ( state = initialTabState, action ) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
    case( ENABLE_TAB ):
        return (
            state.mergeDeep(fromJS(action.payload))
        );
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I am adopting Immutable now.

Comment: Nice! I really enjoy working with it! I feel it keeps me explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a state that looks like this:

```
{
  state: {
    meta: {
      data: {
        foo: 'bar',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

And you want it to look like this:

```
{
  state: {
    meta: {
      data: {
        foo: 'bar',
        hello: 'world',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

First, create a function to update the nested property you want to get at:

```
const update = (data, obj) => {
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    data,
    obj,
  )
}
```

And then, call that `update` function like this:

```
return Object.assign(
  {},
  state,
  {
    meta: {
      data: update(state.meta.data, {hello: 'world'}),
    },
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use deep assign to merge object trees like this.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/deep-assign

Comment: Thanks for letting me know David, I was under the impression that Object.assign deep merges too.