# How to conditionally $merge or $set nested data in a redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a simple `SEARCH_SUCCESS` reducer that [updates](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) api response into state mapped by id like this:

```
[searchActionTypes.SEARCH_SUCCESS]: (state, { companies }) => {
    return update(state, { $merge: _.indexBy(companies, '_id') })
},
```

However, because my state is mapped by id, this is *replacing* any existing companies in state. This is a problem because I want to preserve extra data stored on existing companies in state.

I could just iterate through the companies and manually `$merge` state:

```
const newState = _.deepClone(state)
_.forEach(companies, company => newState[company._id] = state[company._id] ?
    update(state[company._id], { $merge: company }) : company
)
return newState
```

But this feels clunky. Is there a more elegant way to update nested state that will conditionally `$merge` or `$set` if keys are not present?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135779/updating-nested-data-in-redux-store . See also https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr .

Comment: The question you linked to is a generic question about updating redux state with an accepted answer that recommends using react-addons-update. I am already using this helper and link to it in my question. Abramov (creator of redux) also responds and recommends normalizer. My data is already normalized, hence why I am indexing records by ID.

Comment: To clarify, my question addresses a shortcoming of the update addon $merge operator, in that it only merges shallow, much like lodash assign.

Answer (score 1):

After some fiddling, I just abandoned the update `$merge` operator, because it is essentially equivalent to lodash `assign` and went with a combo of lodash `cloneDeep` and `merge` like this:

```
[dupeSearchActionTypes.SEARCH_SUCCESS]: (state, { companies }) => {
  // manually _.merge companies into state because react-addons-update $merge is shallow
  return _.merge(_.cloneDeep(state), _.indexBy(companies, '_id'))
},
```