# Error using react-update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My store:

```
{
    people: [
        {
            id: 12345,
            name: Person 1
        },
        {
            id: 54321,
            name: Person 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to update the `name` property on Person 1. I'm using `react-addons-update` like this:

```
update(state, {
    people: {
        [action.person.id]: {
            name: action.person.name
        }
    }
}
```

Where `action.person` is an object `{ id: 12345, name: New name }`.

However, I keep getting an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined(…)

This is being thrown in `react-addons-update`'s `update` method. Specifically,

```
for (var k in spec) {
    if (!(ALL_COMMANDS_SET.hasOwnProperty(k) && ALL_COMMANDS_SET[k])) {
        nextValue[k] = update(value[k], spec[k]);    // Error occurs here
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell the problem is that when `nextValue`, `value` and `spec` are all set to `people`, `k` is set to `action.person.id`. And of course that id doesn't exist in the array (it's an array of people).

So my question is, what can I pass in instead of `[action.person.id]` to do this? According to both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135779/updating-nested-data-in-redux-store) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628774/how-to-update-single-value-inside-specific-array-item-in-redux) what I have should be working.

Comment: ps you should be using [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) – `react-addons-update` is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
update(state, {
    people: {
        $apply: (people) => people.map((person) => {
            if(person.id !== action.person.id) {
                return person;
            }

            return {
                ...person,
                name: action.person.name
            }
        })
    }
}
```