# Updating an inner element of object using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need a little help with updating an inner element of an object using Object.assign in my redux reducer.

To better explain the scenario, I'm using NBA teams. I have an NBA object in my redux store. I'm now trying to update only the teamMembers for a particular team. My NBA object looks like this:

```
{
   teams: [
       {
          teamId: 123,
          teamName: "Los Angeles Lakers"
          teamMembers: [
             {id: "kbryant", fullName: "Kobe Bryant"},
             {id: "bingram", fullName: "Brandon Ingram"}
          ]
        },
        {
          teamId: 234,
          teamName: "Miami Heat"
          teamMembers: [
             {id: "cbosh", fullName: "Chris Bosh"},
             {id: "tjohnson", fullName: "Tyler Johnson"}
          ]
        }
   ]
}
```

I pass both teamId and members to the reducer through my action i.e. action.teamId and action.members.

This is what I have so far:

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
   nba: Object.assign({}, state.nba, {
      teams: Object.assign({}, state.nba.teams, {
         teamId[action.teamId] // I'm stuck here...
      })
   })
})
```

How do I update the teamMembers of a particular team? I know I'm almost there but could use a little help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating nested data in redux store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135779/updating-nested-data-in-redux-store)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Also the suggestions for that question don't apply. I'm using Object.assign only.

Comment: You could wrap the relevant `Object.assign` call in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and do some work inside of there, including any data mutation.  Just make sure to mutate and `return` the new object made by `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Are you trying to add or remove an object from `teamMembers`?

Comment: @Sam You're trying to achieve the same thing and using `update` from the immutability-helper is a valid solution.

Comment: Neither! Simply replace the value of teamMembers. The action.members contains all the members.

Comment: Why is `Object.assign()` necessary?

Comment: How else can I update the state keeping everything exactly the same except for a particular team's members?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I avoid using any third party solutions as much as possible. Looks like the immutability helper is already deprecated. Now they're suggesting yet another third party helper. This is why I avoid using third party solutions. I really should be able to handle this scenario using simply Object.assign

Comment: Have not tried `reactjs` or `redux`. Assigning directly to the object does not have same effect?

Comment: @guest271314 No, because we cannot mutate things in redux. That's why we use Object.assign so that we create a new copy of an existing object and put that in redux store.

Comment: I suggest storing teams as a map - replace array by object with IDs as keys. this way, it's much easier to update particular entity (this applies to any entity collection). Then, do follow link in very first comment and use `update` helper shipped by React team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the code you had with a dynamic index property, which is intended to identify which entry in the `teams` array needs updating. The ES6 syntax allows dynamic properties in object literals, by wrapping the dynamic expression in square brackets, like this: `{ [index]: value }`, where `index` is a variable or other expression.

Here is the final solution:

```js
function getNewState(state, action) {
    var index = state.nba.teams.findIndex( t => t.teamId == action.teamId );
    if (index == -1) return state; // team not found
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        nba: Object.assign({}, state.nba, {
            teams: Object.assign([], state.nba.teams, {
                [index]: Object.assign({}, state.nba.teams[index], { 
                    teamMembers: action.teamMembers 
                })
            })
        })
    });
}

var state = {
    nba: {
        teams: [{
            teamId: 123,
            teamName: "Los Angeles Lakers",
            teamMembers: [
                {id: "kbryant", fullName: "Kobe Bryant"},
                {id: "bingram", fullName: "Brandon Ingram"}
            ]
        }, {
            teamId: 234,
            teamName: "Miami Heat",
            teamMembers: [
                {id: "cbosh", fullName: "Chris Bosh"},
                {id: "tjohnson", fullName: "Tyler Johnson"}
            ]
        }]
    }
};

var action = { teamId: 123, teamMembers: [{id: "lnance", fullName: "Larry Nance"}] };
var newState = getNewState(state, action);
console.log(newState);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that this kind of manipulation becomes a lot easier with a library like [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: I think this is a pretty good solution i.e. figuring out the index then updating the values. It still took me a while to get it to work. After debugging it for a while trying to figure out what's going on, I realized during the update -- because I'm using Object.assign, I was converting teamMembers from an array to an object which ended up breaking the rest of my code. So instead of using Object.assign to create a new copy of teamMembers, I used slice instead and it worked fine. I will look into the immutable library. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear it worked out. I think `Object.assign` should also work, but by providing an empty array as first argument, to make sure it is always an array: `Object.assign([], ...)`. I updated it just now. But `slice` is fine also of course.

Comment: I didn't know I could use Object.assign with an empty array. Just learned one more thing. You've been super helpful. Really appreciate it! I'll up-vote your answer.