# How to update certain key values in an object nested in the redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I have the following data :

```
Project : {id:10,
           requirements: [{id:1,
                           title:test},
                          {id:2,
                            title:test2}]
          }
```

and

```
action.payload : {id:1,
                  title:changed_title}
```

What i wish to update the requirement object of `id:1`
within my redux reducer.

Heres what i have so far but it doesn't seem to be working and its super messy:

```
  case 'requirements_update': return (updateObject(state, project: {...state.project , requirements: state.project.requirements.filter(requirement => 
                                                                                                                                            {if(requirement.requirement_id === action.payload.requirement_id)
                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                            return(action.payload) }
                                                                                                                                            })}))
```

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135779/updating-nested-data-in-redux-store

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and id check to update project

```
project : state.project.map(project => project.id === payload.id ? payload : project)
```

Answer (score 0):

The double spreading at the bottom is to merge current requirement properties with action payload, (action payload properties will have priority since they will override existing ones)

```
case 'requirements_update':
  return {...state, state.project: {...state.project , requirements: state.project.requirements.map(requirement => {
    if (requirement.id === action.payload.id) {
      return {...requirement, ...action.payload}
    } else {
      return requirement
    }
  }}}
```